# Modified format of title / Chapter number for the table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I am using a modified Chapter formatting found at http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html and I have a problem as it creates a chapter number for the table of contents, list of figures and list of tables.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,journal,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \thickhrulefill\quad
        \scshape \@chapapp{} \thechapter
        \quad \thickhrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \hrule
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \par
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \hrule
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \thickhrulefill
        \scshape  \thechapter
        \thickhrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \hrule
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \par
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \hrule
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Title1}
\blindtext

\chapter{Title2}
\blindtext

\chapter{Title3}
\blindtext

\listoffigures
\listoftables

\end{document}
```

While it gives the chapter number above the chapter title, as expected, it also places a number above the table of contents, the list of figures and the list of tables; as shown below:
[image]

Is there a way to remove these numbers without affecting the numbers of the chapters?

Answer (score 1):

The ToC, etc, use `\chapter*` for their titles. Your redefinition of `\chapter*` includes a chapter number.

```
    % toctitleprob.tex  SE 615965

\documentclass[11pt,journal,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \thickhrulefill\quad
        \scshape \@chapapp{} \thechapter
        \quad \thickhrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \hrule
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \par
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \hrule
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \thickhrulefill
%%%        \scshape  \thechapter %%% I think you don't want this
        \thickhrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \hrule
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \par
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \hrule
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Title1}
\blindtext

\chapter*{Starred Title}
\blindtext

\end{document}

\chapter{Title2}
\blindtext

\end{document}

\chapter{Title3}
\blindtext

\listoffigures
\listoftables

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]